# PHP: RegEx for nested {IF} {ENDIF} Conditions

Tags: php, regex, if-statement

I am searching the whole day for a RegEx that matches just the inner {IF} - {ENDIF}-Statement in a nested condition code. Does anyone have an idea?

for example:

```
{IF bla}Text 1{ELSEIF ble}Text 2 {IF bli}Text 2.1{ELSE blo}Text 2.1{ENDIF} Main text end{/ENDIF}
```

I just want to get

```
{IF bli}Text 2.1{ELSE blo}Text 2.1{ENDIF}
```

i tried `#\{IF .*\}.*\{ENDIF\}#is` but this is not working as i only get the whole string.

And also important: The code can have several lines and line breaks!

the bla, ble, bli etc are dynamic and can differ

Comment: I dont think regexp is the way here (similiar to parsing XML/HTML). I would consider parsing text manualy (traversing text, when you hit { you check for keyword). This way you can build a tree yourself and then take any node you need.

Comment: thanks, after long searching and failing i used that solution.

Answer (score 1):

Inner IF-ELSE:

`{IF(?!.*{IF).*?}.*?{ENDIF}`

- `(?!.*{IF)` looks ahead from that position and asserts it won't match
- The lazy quantifiers `?` are an instruction to stop at the earliest match.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/CgRdV0/1)

Answer (score 0):

This grabs your inner IF block:

```
/{IF(?:.*?(?={IF)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.*?){ENDIF}/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JgfcYN/3) (279 steps)

The pattern uses `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` and "disqualifies" any IF blocks that contain an inner IF block.  This way you only get the innermost IF block.

Code:  ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/7e055e1c135d05e8b695666de797a4e3995122d4))

```
$string='{IF bla}Text 1{ELSEIF ble}Text 2 {IF bli}Text 2.1{ELSE blo}Text 2.1{ENDIF} Main text end{/ENDIF}';
echo  preg_match('/{IF(?:.*?(?={IF)(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|.*?){ENDIF}/',$string,$match)?$match[0]:'fail';
```

Output:

```
{IF bli}Text 2.1{ELSE blo}Text 2.1{ENDIF}
```

---

Or faster/better with negative lookahead:

```
/{IF(?!.*{IF).*?{ENDIF}/
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/JgfcYN/4) (190 steps)